# List of strings in a list

Tags: python

I have multiple lists of strings, inside a list. I want to change the strings that are digits into integers.

ex:-

```
L1=[['123','string','list']['words','python','456']['code','678','links']]
```

What i want is:

```
[[123,'string','list']['words','python',456]['code',678,'links']]
```

I have tried using-

```
W=range(len(L1))       
Q=range(2)
if (L1[W][Q]).isdigit():
   (L1[W][Q])=(int(L1[W][Q]))
```

when I tried the above code, I got an error.

Comment: Please share with us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [str.isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
L1=[['123','string','list'],['words','python','456'],['code','678','links']]
for item in L1:
    for i in range(0,len(item)):
        if(item[i].isdigit()):
            item[i] = int(item[i])

print(L1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
>>> mylist = [['123','string','list'], ['words','python','456'], ['code','678','links']]
>>> [ [(int(item) if item.isdigit() else item) for item in sublist] for sublist in mylist]
[[123, 'string', 'list'], ['words', 'python', 456], ['code', 678, 'links']]
```